# BST; the sum of BST elements which are greater then the sum of their direct children

Tags: c, function, binary-search-tree

So the task is to write a function which returns the sum of BST elements which are greater then the sum of their direct children. Do not count leaf nodes. I did it this way, the base case when the tree is empty return 0, and if it doesn't have sons also return 0. Then I checked if node has one or two children and the condition for the sums.

```
int sum(struct node* root) 
{
if (root== NULL) return 0;
if (root->right == NULL && root->left==NULL) return 0;
if (root->right!= NULL && root->left != NULL)
{
    if (((root->right)->key + (root->left)->key) < root->key) return root->key;
}
if (root->right != NULL && root->left==NULL)
{
    if ((root->right)->key< root->key) return root->key;
}
if (root->left != NULL && root->right==NULL)
{
    if ((root->left)->key < root->key) return root->key;
}
else return sum(root->right) + sum(root->left);
}
```

Main:

```
struct node* root = NULL;

add(&root,-4);
add(&root,6);
add(&root,8);
add(&root,-11);
add(&root,5);
add(&root,7);
add(&root,-20);
printf("%d",sum(root));
```

It should return -1 (6+8-11-4), but my function doesn't work I don't know why.

Comment: In English, when describing things like tree structures and processes hierarchies, the terms 'son' and 'daughter' (and 'father' and 'mother', etc) are avoided.  Use the gender-neutral 'parent' and 'child' (and 'grandparent', 'grandchild'), etc.  (Sibling for 'brother' or 'sister'.)

Comment: You can, and should, write `(root->right)->key` as the unambiguous `root->right->key`. The parentheses are not necessary; they're unexpected by experienced C programmers.  You sometimes need parentheses if you're dealing with weird stuff like pointers to pointers to structures — so `(*proot)->right->key` — or something similar.  But for the regular case, the parentheses are mildly obfuscatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `else` clause will never be executed; your previous conditions have dealt with all possibilities.

However, the expression should be executed.  You either need to add `+ sum(root->left) + sum(root->right)` as part of the three non-degenerate `return` statements, or you need to save the `root->key` in a local variable (defaulting to zero) and fall through to `return return_value + sum(root->left) + sum(root->right);`.

Hence (using the abbreviation `rv` for 'return value':

```
int sum(struct node* root)
{
    int rv = 0;
    if (root == NULL || (root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL))
        return rv;
    if (root->right != NULL && root->left != NULL)
    {
        if ((root->right->key + root->left->key) < root->key)
            rv = root->key;
    }
    if (root->right != NULL && root->left == NULL)
    {
        if (root->right->key < root->key)
           rv = root->key;
    }
    if (root->left != NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
        if (root->left->key < root->key)
            rv = root->key;
    }
    return rv + sum(root->right) + sum(root->left);
}
```

<sup>*Warning: pristine code, unsullied by any attempt to compile it.*</sup>

You could use an `else if` chain for the last three 'outer' `if` tests (with an `else` clause instead of the last test) to avoid repeated tests.  Whether there'd be a measurable difference is debatable; an optimizer might even make the change for itself.